# How do you encrypt the entire Ubuntu Partition in a Dual Boot System?

Tags: encryption

I am planning to make my laptop have Windows 7, and Ubuntu. I plan to set up the partitions like so:

```
/dev/sda1 = windows <p>
/dev/sda2 = ubuntu boot (doesnt have to be encrypted) <p>
/dev/sda3 = ubuntu / <p>
```

How can I install Ubuntu onto `/dev/sda3`, and fully encrypt `/dev/sda3`? (I don't want to simply encrypt my home folder, but rather the / directory due to /apps containing my work)

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to set up a partition configuration like this.

***Note:*** I'm only providing the links to the appropriate pages because the procedure is quite long and also since most of the links are Ubuntu Wiki pages.

### If a LVM already exists

This can be used if you already have partitions set up.

From Ubuntu Wiki:

> With the recipe...the Desktop CD can be used to install Ubuntu on a
>   previously created (optionally encrypted) LVM.

***Related Links/Sources:***

- [Ubuntu Wiki - EncryptedFileSystemsViaUbiquity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsViaUbiquity)

### Installation on a fresh HDD (no partitions or LVM)

This method will:

> 1. Perform a minimal server install
> 2. Create encrypted partition and copy minimal install to it
> 3. Modify grub's menu.lst and fstab

This is like installing Ubuntu first and then encrypting the partitions.

***Related Links/Sources:***

- [Ubuntu Wiki - EncryptedFileSystemsOnIntrepid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemOnIntrepid)
- [svenfila.wordpress.com - Encrypt Root Partition Without Re-installing Linux](http://svenfila.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/encrypt-root-partition-without-re-installing-linux/)

### Encrypting Full Disk (won't be able to install Windows)

When you install Ubuntu, there's a checkbox to *Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security*.

[image: Ubuntu Full Disk Encryption]

[image: Ubuntu Full Disk Encryption Key Selection]

> This is good news not just for Ubuntu users, but for users of all
>   GNU/Linux distributions that are downstream from Ubuntu. The above
>   screenshots come from ubiquity, the simple graphical live CD installer
>   that Canonical developed. Every distribution that uses ubiquity as an
>   installer will soon also make it easy for users to use FDE. The
>   up-and-coming distribution Linux Mint, for example, is based on
>   Ubuntu, but there is currently no simple way to install it with disk
>   encryption.

***Related Links/Sources:***

- [EFF - Privacy in Ubuntu 12.10](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/11/privacy-ubuntu-1210-full-disk-encryption)